# Shapely Difference on multiple MultiLineStrings

Tags: python, geometry, shapely, multilinestring, set-difference

I have written a function `blade` that returns a Shapely MultiLineString. I would like to be able to run `blade` `n`-times, and have each subsequent call only be the difference of all the previous calls.

```
blade_list = []
    for k in range(self.number_of_blades):
        the_x = vsk.random(self.x_margin, vsk.width - self.x_margin)
        the_length = vsk.random(self.min_length_of_blade, self.max_length_of_blade)
        the_sway = vsk.random(self.min_sway_width, self.max_sway_width)
        a_blade = blade(the_x, the_length, the_sway)
        blade_list.append(a_blade)

    def get_intersected(linesstring, multilinestrings):
        inter_list = []
        for mls in multilinestrings:
            for ls in mls:
                if ls.intersects(linesstring):
                    inter_list.append(ls)
        return inter_list

    occlude_list = []
    for blades in blade_list:
        for segments in blades:
            inter_list = get_intersected(segments, blade_list)
            for occluded_lines in inter_list:
                occluded_lines = occluded_lines.difference(segments)
                occlude_list.append(occluded_lines)

    for ls in occlude_list:
        vsk.geometry(ls)
```

[This is the output from running above. The intended effect would be each 'blade' being overlapped by the next, but as it is you can still 'see through them'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQe5s.png)

I'm still teaching myself, so apologies in advance if this ends up being just a very silly problem, but I've been running into walls the last couple days trying to figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to make the function return both a multilinestring and a polygon.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).